# Why is JDBC driver not necessary for H2

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, h2

I have a very simple Java getting started app using the H2 in-memory DB:

```
String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:./test";
try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
                Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement() ){
    // executing SQLs, getting a result set, etc.
    ...
}
// Catching & handling exceptions
```

The app works, however, I wonder why don't I have to call `Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);` anywhere in my code? In all H2 quick starts, they load the class manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that for any JDBC driver that is not many years old. Drivers are auto-discovered thanks to the service provider mechanism of Java, [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html):

> The DriverManager methods getConnection and getDrivers have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver. For example, to load the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file would contain the entry:
>
> ```
> my.sql.Driver
> ```
>
> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName(). Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.

Note that, contrary to what the title of your question says, the JDBC driver is necessary. Using Class.forName() to load it is what is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense, thank you. And yes, I thought that the driver was loaded automatically somewhere, but could not find it on the H2 websites; my title is poorly worded.